# The range in the Excel formula changes after insert-shift, how can I stop it changing?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel 2010 formula in an Excel cell like this (the formula lies in column T):

```
=SUMIF($B$14:$B$44335;$T8;$E$14:$E$44335)
```

This formula does this: It finds the cells in the `Range("B14:B44335")` which have the value as `Range("T8")` (For example, between `Range("B192:B370")`), then it sums up the values in the column E (For example, sums up between `Range("E192:E370")`).

The formula works fine, but a background VBA-code couses problem. This VBA code sometimes extends or shorten `Range("B14:E44335")`. The VBA-code uses `insert shift:=xlDown` or `delete shift:=xlUp` for extending or shortening.

Insert shifting (inserting 178 rows) in VBA causes that the formula changes like this:

```
=SUMIF($B$192:$B$43623;$T8;$E$192:$E$43623)
```

So the formula also shifts from `B14` to `B192`.

This is strange, because the formula is in the column T, and the VBA-code has nothing to do with the column T.

I tried to give a name to the range like, when I write `Countries`, then Excel selects the `Range("B14:E44335")`, so

```
=SUMIF(Countries;$T8;$E$14:$E$44335)
```

But i got the same problem again. After `Insert Shift`, `Countries` shows `Range(B192:B43623")`

In anyway, how can I keep the range in my formula permanent, no matter what happens in other cells?

Comment: re: `$B$14:$B$44335`  are 14 and 44335 "fixed" and never change? or are they actually based on some logic ?

Comment: Excel's functionality will automatically update row and column references when rows or columns are inserted / deleted across a formula range reference that intersects the inserted / deleted cells. For example, if the rows were inserted / deleted after row 14, the `B14` in your example would not be affected, only the bottom rows. Since you say the code does not even affect column T, can you change the code to only insert / delete the necessary rows / columns instead of the `EntireRow` or `EntireColumn`? In this way, your existing formula references would not be affected.

Comment: The other option (a real hack, but ...) is to have the VBA code reset your formula after the insertion / deletion.

Comment: @ditto it must be a fixed range, always the same range

Comment: @scott-holtzman VBA-code insert-shift into the beginning of the range also sometimes. So that's why it changes the `B14` when VBA does insert shift to the beginning of the range

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes, maybe it is the only solution to copy the formula from VBA to the cell in every run.

Comment: @user3714330 - see Ditto answer below. It think that will work and its better than messing with the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
  =SUMIF(offset($b$1,13,0,44321, 1), $t8, offset($e$1,13,0,44321))
```

This uses OFFSET to create the fixed range: 14 to 44335 .. if that should be a fixed range, you should be golden.
If not, you need to figure out some formula/logic to calculate the 13 and the 44321 .. ;)

For reasons mentioned by Scott in comments above, Excel is adjusting your ranges, offset bypasses that ;)

Comment: very nice solution :)